# How to create an IoTHub resource in a resource group using java?

Tags: java, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am able to create a resource group in azure using java libraries but not getting how to create an IoTHub resource in that group.

I have tried using genericResources but it's throwing an exception of missing Sku information. Unfortunately there is no method to set SKU info in the genericResources creation.

Error:com.microsoft.azure.CloudException: Sku information is missing.

Comment: I used another way to create an IOT hub resource. If you can share your way of using genericResources, I can have a further research for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, [Azure Management library for java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java) does not cover all the services in Azure portal. Unfortunately, we cannot use it to manage IOT hub now.

I did some test, and found 2 optional workarounds:

1. Use Azure REST API to [create an IOT hub resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource/createorupdate)
2. Use Azure Java SDK to deploy an IOT hub resource with template:

Template:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "sku_name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "sku_units": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "d2c_partitions": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "features": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2019-07-01-preview",
            "type": "Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "eventHubEndpoints": {
                    "events": {
                        "retentionTimeInDays": 1,
                        "partitionCount": "[parameters('d2c_partitions')]"
                    }
                },
                "features": "[parameters('features')]"
            },
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('sku_name')]",
                "capacity": "[parameters('sku_units')]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Java code:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.management.Azure;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.DeploymentMode;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.fluentcore.arm.Region;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public static void DeployTest(Azure azure) {
    try(InputStream templatein = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream( "D:\\iottemplate\\template.json"));
        StringWriter templateWriter = new StringWriter();
    ){
        // Read the template.json file
        IOUtils.copy(templatein, templateWriter);

        // Convert template to JSON object
        JSONObject templateNode = new JSONObject(templateWriter.toString());

        // Add default value for parameters
        JSONObject parameterValue = templateNode.optJSONObject("parameters");
        parameterValue.optJSONObject("sku_name").put("defaultValue","B1");
        parameterValue.optJSONObject("sku_units").put("defaultValue","1");
        parameterValue.optJSONObject("d2c_partitions").put("defaultValue","4");
        parameterValue.optJSONObject("location").put("defaultValue","southeastasia");
        parameterValue.optJSONObject("features").put("defaultValue","None");
        parameterValue.optJSONObject("name").put("defaultValue","jackiottest567");

        // Deploy
        azure.deployments().define("CreateIOTHub")
                .withNewResourceGroup("JackIotTest1", Region.ASIA_SOUTHEAST)
                .withTemplate(templateNode.toString())
                .withParameters("{}")
                .withMode(DeploymentMode.INCREMENTAL)
                .create();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jack for your response. The Generic resource one is not having any method to add the SKU info :( . I used the 2nd option which u mentioned and it worked perfectly. However in the first I was getting an authentication error. I am wondering what creds to be given and does it use basic auth scheme to validate.

Comment: One more thing Jack could you please let me know where i can get these basic json templates for IOT related stuffs. As i have to create IOT Edge inside the hub.

Comment: Official quickstart templates:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/

Comment: I am able to create the Hub using Azure rest api too :)